# Try to find the proper elements to make it a Galois Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Problem:

> Suppose that $a$ is an integer not less than $1$. Let $\omega=\sqrt{3+a\sqrt{5}}$. We need to find all $a$ such that $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)/\mathbb{Q}$ is a Galois extension. Then find their Galois group respectively.

It's is easy to know that the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ is $f=(x^2-3)^2-5a^2$ since $a\geq1$. If we want the extension to be Galois, we need $|Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\omega)/\mathbb{Q})|=4$. Since $f$ has four roots which are $\omega, -\omega, \omega'=\sqrt{3-a\sqrt{5}}, -\omega'$, the the images of $\omega$ of the potential four automorphisms are these four roots.

Thus we need that $\omega'\in \mathbb{Q}(\omega)$. $\omega'=\sqrt{3-a\sqrt{5}}=\sqrt{\frac{9-5a^2}{3+a\sqrt{5}}}=\frac{\sqrt{9-5a^2}}{\omega}$. So we need that $9-5a^2$ is a square. So the only answer is $1$ since $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Then $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois since $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ is a splitting field of the irreducible polynomial $f$.

I think this could be the right solution.

Comment: Proving that $f$ is the minimal polynomial may need a bit more care. How did you justify that it won't be a product of two quadratics? It does follow from your list of the roots because you can examine all the possible quadratic factors. However, if we had a $6$ in place of $3$ then the choice $a=2$ would cause $f$ to split. Basically because $\sqrt{6+2\sqrt5}=1+\sqrt5$. If you checked this out in the actual case, then you'll be fine :-)

Comment: However, 3 is smaller than 5. So you can't write $3+a\sqrt{5}$ as a square.

Comment: True, that will help. But, without leaving the realm of algebraic integers $(3+\sqrt5)/2$ is the square of $(1+\sqrt5)/2$. And actually $2+\sqrt5$ is a cube, namely that of $(1+\sqrt5)/2$. The point of including the latter example is to show that the coefficients of an eventual root w.r.t. the basis $\{1,\sqrt5\}$ need not be integers. Basic algebraic number theory does show that those coefficients must be either integers or half-integers. Anyway, checking that no pair of zeros of your quartic have both sum and product rationals, you can conclude that the quartic is irreducible.

Comment: Anyway, the +1 is from me.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $\omega'$ should be $\sqrt{3-a\sqrt5}$, and the condition for
Galoisness is $9-5a^2$ should be a square or $5$ times a square.
To see this,
we need $\omega$ and $\omega'$ to generate the same extension of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)$. By Kummer theory, this is the case iff $(3+a\sqrt5)(3-a\sqrt5)$
is a square in $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)$. An integer is a square in this field, iff
it is a square or $5$ times a square. But this latter case cannot occur...